# Ajax-loader in thymeleaf spring

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I using a POST request in my thymeleaf/spring MVC application.

```
$('#rpp').on('change', function() {
    var url = [[${url_current}]];
    var rpp = $('#rpp').val(); 
    var data = {
        rpp: rpp
    };

    $('#productList').load(url, data);
});
```

This is my code. How to add ajax-loader until the items loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

```
$('#rpp').on('change', function() {
   var url = [[${url_current}]];
   var rpp = $('#rpp').val(); 
   var data = {
       rpp: rpp
   };
   $('body').append('<div id="ajax-loading"></div>');
   $('#productList').load(url, data, function(){ // callback when completed
      $('#ajax-loading').remove();
   });
});
```

where *#ajax-loader* is styled with a loading.gif or what you choose.

Comment: It almost works but the DIV #ajax-loading loaded on the bottom of page. What to do, to load where is #productList DIV. Example: When click on button with id="rpp" to hide #productList and to show loading. Thanks.

Comment: @PYovchevski you'll have to either append it to the productlist parent or style it with absolute. You'll have to show your HTML markup and styles for me to give you a correct answer